# Trying to make images as sprites in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Why isn't this code working? I'm trying to create a class to quickly create players for my game in pygame. I was trying to create a sprite based on what he did in this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDu8mcAlY4E, and his seemed to work fine.

```
class Player(Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self,x,y,picture_path,width,height):
      super().__init__()
      self.image = pygame.image.load(picture_path)
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    
    def move(self):
        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy
        self.dy += GRAVITY
        
    def jump(self):
        self.dy -= 15
        
    def left(self):
        self.dx -= 6
        if self.dx < -12:
          self.dx = -12
        
    def right(self):
        self.dx = 6
        if self.dx > 12:
            self.dx = 12



player = Player(600,0,'nin.png',20,20)
player2 = Player(600,40,'nin.png',20,20)
```

If you want the error for this here it is;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 107, in <module>
    player = Player(600,0,'nin.png',20,20)
  File "main.py", line 77, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'x', 'y', 'width', and 'height'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 107, in <module>
    player = Player(600,0,'nin.png',20,20)
  File "main.py", line 77, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'x', 'y', 'width', and 'height'

```

Answer (score 0):

**The base class must be [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) instead of your own `Sprite` class.**

Pygame uses [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Spritel) objects and [`pygame.sprite.Group`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) objects to manage *Sprites*. [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The former delegates the to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group [...]

The later uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

See the very basic example:

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-Sprite](https://replit.com/@Rabbid76/PyGame-Sprite#main.py)</kbd>

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self, center_pos, image):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = center_pos)
    
    def update(self, surf):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_d]-keys[pygame.K_a]) * 5
        self.rect.y += (keys[pygame.K_s]-keys[pygame.K_w]) * 5
        self.rect.clamp_ip(surf.get_rect())

player_surf = pygame.image.load('Bird64.png').convert_alpha()
player = Player(window.get_rect().center, player_surf)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([player])

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    all_sprites.update(window)

    window.fill(0)
    all_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```